# Distributed Testing with Jmeter

Tags: testing, jmeter, load-testing, stress-testing, distributed-testing

I am using Jmeter 2.8 and trying to do distributed (master-slave) testing for the first time.
I setup everything fine

- set Ip addresses  in JMeter.properties
- run Jmater-server.bat on all machines

but when I run test(a very simple request) it gets failed:

Request:

```
http://localhost:8080/web/login?credentials=<credential><userId>WillieWonka
</userId><passwd><![CDATA[WillieWonka]]></passwd></credential>
```

Error I am getting is

```
 org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connection to http://localhost:8080 refused
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:190)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.open(ManagedClientConnectionImpl.java:294)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:640)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:479)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:906)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:805)
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl.sample(HTTPHC4Impl.java:284)
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerProxy.sample(HTTPSamplerProxy.java:62)
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1075)
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1064)
at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.process_sampler(JMeterThread.java:426)
at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:255)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
 Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:127)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:180)
```

While server is up and running (I tested this request running from localMachine only, It is working fine).

What is wrong?
What I am missing?

Answer (score 1):

I have resolved this issue, replaced

```
localhost:8080
```

with

```
computerName:8080
```

and start application server via start.bat instead run.bat

now it is working fine.